# How can I add intertext to multilines of formulas?

Tags: math-mode, lyx

In LaTeX, I know how to do it, just writing `\intertext{This is a text.}` between the parantheses of the `align*`,I wrote below. But in LyX, it does not read the command `\intertext`. I am temporarily using the command `\mathrm` with space `\` , but I guess there should be another way to put texts.

```
\begin{align*}
\dot{y}&=\dot{x}-\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\cdot \dot{x}\\
&=\Lambda x+v(x)+\cdots-\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\cdot(\Lambda 
x+v(x)+\cdots)\\
\intertext{This is a text.}
&=\Lambda (y+h(x))+v(y+h(x))+\cdots-\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\cdot(\Lambda (y+h(x))+\cdots)\\
\end{align*}
```

Any comment would be appreciated!

---

I included `\usepackage{mathtools}` in LaTeX Preamble, now LyX compiles well. But I think it does not read the space (blank), what I can do is only `\intertext{word}`, not `\intertext{two words}'. In detail,

[image]

LaTeX code:

```
& \leq\sup_{\|g\|_{p'}\leq1}\|f\|_{p}\|\tilde{K}\ast g\|_{p'}\\

& \intertext{dkfjdkfjt}\\

& \lesssim\sup_{\|g\|_{p'}\leq1}\|f\|_{p}\|g\|_{p'}=\|f\|_{p}.\\
```

The first is good, on the other hand, the second is not.

[image]

LaTeX code:

```
& \leq\sup_{\|g\|_{p'}\leq1}\|f\|_{p}\|\tilde{K}\ast g\|_{p'}\\

& \intertext{dkfjdkfjt}dfdfdf\\

& \lesssim\sup_{\|g\|_{p'}\leq1}\|f\|_{p}\|g\|_{p'}=\|f\|_{p}.\\
```

My opinion is that the space bar lets the cursor out of the brackets of the `\intertext{}`. As a temporary measure, I type the blank with the backslash.

---

As commented, I focused on the mark `&` in front of the `\intertext{}`, so I tried `\intertext` in several places, but sill the space bar does not stay in the brackets {} of the `\intertext{}`.

[image]

Comment: `\intertext` is defined by `amsmath`/`mathtools`. Do you include any of these packages? Also, is it just a highlighting error in LyX or do you actually get an compilation error? If so, which one?

Comment: Your example works fine with document class `article`. What result do you get when your say "it does not read the space (blank)?"

Comment: @JJW in Lyx most of LaTeX is hidden, do we do not know what you see

Comment: That is the issue, there should not be a `&` in front of `\intertext`, What happens if you add it in the left square interface in Lyx? (does it insert a `&` after it?). BTW please look into how we format code here, mark it and hit CTRL-k to have it indented as presented verbatimly.

Comment: I also assume that it is a copying mistake that you present blank lines between them the lines?

Comment: @daleif For the blank lines, it is simply because I don't know how to separate the lines without blank lines... And also I edited.

Comment: I just tested lyx, `\intertext` works just fine in a simple document, just make sure to add it in the left one of the litle blue boxes, not the right one. Note that I inserted it as TeX code.

Comment: @daleif Yes, thanks for comments. In my case, \intertext{} works, and also \mathrm{} as well, but when they are enclosed in the brackets of align* in LyX, they don't read the space bar, so I have no choice but to type extra backslash to have blank(yeah, I think it is the point of the post, then), but I feel like it's a wrong way. Is it fine for you?

Comment: No it does not work for me either. You should report this to the Lyx developers. (now you also know why most of us does not use editors that writes the code for us, we tend to not like "nannies"). BTW: can you use `\text{...}` and write spaces in that? It is crucial that `\text` allows spaces. Again, it is not something we can do much about. There might be an interface for this in Lyx, just do not know where.

Comment: It might be an idea to post an entirely new question, just about this, then you can point the lyx people towards that question (this one ends up being a bit messy)

Comment: BTW: note the Insert -> Formatting (various spacing commands, though none of them are  `(space)`, one is ``\ `` another is `~`. But you'll tstill have issues if the comment is more than a page.

Comment: Interesting observation, then `\text` command is supported by Lyx, if you type `\text` an interface comes up and you can choose `\text` and Lyx behaves "normally" on it. For `\intertext` there does not seem to be such an interface. As it is a part of the ever standard `masmath` ask the developers to provide an interface for it.

Comment: @daleif I left a short post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489425/how-can-i-use-intertext-normally-in-lyx. Thanks.

Comment: @daleif are you confirming that space bar is not keeping inside `\intertext{braces as you type Evil Red Text}` when the tex box starts `\begin{align*}` I am having no problem inside a tex boundary as described. I know JJW had difficulties with installation due to his locale and his keyboard behaviour could be the root of any spacebar issue, Are you using non ascii keyboard ? I seem to have no problems with UK English layout.

Comment: @KJO I'm at a US keyboard, when I insert `\intertext` via CTRL-L (I think it is) and I write text in the argument, the space key does nothing at all. You can force a space via say CTRL-ALT-SPACE, but looking at the generated source, this is not the same as normally hitting the space key. In contract, if I write `\text`, it can be chosen from a Lyx menu, in the box thus created, space works just fine.

Comment: Ok using CtrlL opens an ERT box I can consecutively type `\intertext{hello world` `\intertext{hello world and add more words` no problem …`} then add more` but those after I typed 2nd brace } will be outside expected behaviour, my understanding is the issue is different inside an align environment so I start the ERT with \begin{align*} and next line \inter offers me \intertext without braces so I manually add the opening and start typing `\intertext{Hello wor`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the user have accepted the link of a short post.